# How to know if user has already logged in in NODE/Express API with express-sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, session

Ok, so I know there are some answers about this one, however, they all deal with the login route. What I am asking about is how to check on every route that needs a user to be logged in.
So far, I have a middleware that is placed in routes that need the user to be logged in:

```
 const logged = function(req,res,next){
     if(req.session?.authenticated){
         next();
     }else{
          next( new Error.. );
     } }
```

is it ok to only check if there's a **session obj** with **authenticated** var (also I have like userID there, in case I need it in the next middleware) ?

**Sessions are stored in MYSQL table neatly!**

Comment: If `req.session.authenticated` is **only** set to `true` for authenticated users and the session is destroyed after either a TTL period or on logout then it would make sense but normal convention is to set a `req.session.user` object and inside that you can set the userid and whether or not they are authenticated.